# Number Input - Step Attribute - format value to 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, attributes, numbers, currency, trailing

I am creating a currency input and I want my counter to be able to go up in pence, however, I currently have an issue:

at the moment when I click the step, I get something like 0.38, 0.39, 0.4, 0.41, 0.42

I would want the "0.4" to actually be 0.40, but im unsure how i manage this, would anyone be able to help?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="number" step="0.10" value="10"></input>
```

You can use HTML5's step attribute to increment by the particular decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the `input` event and format the input's value accordingly.

```js
document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('input', ({target}) => {
    target.value = Number(target.value).toFixed(2);
});
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="number" step="0.01" value="0.00" />
```

The [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) method was made for this, but it's only available on numbers. We infer a `number` from the current (string) value with `Number()` then format it to 2 decimal places using `toFixed`